# TypeError: post() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have my model class:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

and my View:

```
class SubscriptionView(APIView):
    queryset = Subscription.objects.all()

    def post(request):
        email = request.data.get('email')
        print(email)
        save_email = Subscription.objects.create(email=email)
        save_email.save()

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

My model only takes in 1 field which is the email. Not sure why I keep getting 'TypeError: post() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `post` is a method, so the first parameter is `self`:

```
class SubscriptionView(APIView):
    queryset = Subscription.objects.all()

    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data.get('email')
        Subscription.objects.create(email=email)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

It is however quite seldom that one implements a `post` method itself. Usually you work for example with a [**`CreateAPIView`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview), and one can let the serializer, etc. handle all the work.

Answer (score 0):

*post* is an Instance method of Class `SubscriptionView`, while invoking an Instance method Python automatically passes an `object reference` of that class. So you need to receive that object reference in your instance method.

You didn't receive that object reference in your post method that's why Python Interpreter showing you:

```
TypeError: post() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

`but 2 were given` Because Python calling post like, `post(SubscriptionView(), request)` but you receive only `request`

You can receive `object reference` using any name but using `self` is standard.

```
class SubscriptionView(APIView):
    queryset = Subscription.objects.all()

    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data.get('email')
        Subscription.objects.create(email=email)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```